# How to calculating the reoccurring months the first year

Tags: r, date

I want to assign digits to the reoccurring months since the first year. the `lubridate` packages has `month` that calculated the months only up to 12 in a year, i.e.

```
month(e$date)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 1 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6
```

However, I was looking for something like this:

```
month  date

1  2019-01-1
2  2019-02-1
3  2019-03-1
4  2019-04-1
5  2019-05-1
6  2019-06-1
7  2019-07-1
8  2019-08-1
9 2019-09-1
10 2019-10-1
11 2019-11-1
12 2019-12-1
13 2020-01-1
14 2020-02-1
15 2020-03-1
16 2020-04-1
17 2020-05-1
18 2020-06-1
19 2020-07-1
20 2020-08-1
21 2020-09-1
22 2020-10-1
23 2020-11-1
24 2020-12-1
25 2021-01-1
26 2021-02-1
27 2021-03-1
28 2021-04-1
29 2021-05-1
30 2021-06-1

month(e$date)
 [1]  1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  5
[26]  3  2  4  1  6
```

Is there a way for the digits to continue on from 12 when the next year is given? Of course this would be more complex when there is a larger dataset, with the dates scattered, so how could I get this to work based on the earliest year & month?

Some reproducible dates:

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(18262, 17897, 17928, 17956, 
17987, 18017, 18048, 18078, 18109, 18140, 18170, 18201, 18231, 
18293, 18322, 18353, 18383, 18414, 18444, 18475, 18506, 18536, 
18567, 18597, 18748, 18687, 18659, 18718, 18628, 18779), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))
```

Comment: These are the first 4 elements of your date column: c("2020-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-02-01", "2019-03-01"). Do you want to sort the dates before the transformation? I see your desired output column is sorted.

Comment: If every month in the given interval is represented, you can just use 1:nrow on a sorted df, as per Ronak Shahs answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 30 days in a month you can subtract all the dates with minimum value.

```
round(as.numeric(df$date - min(df$date))/30)
```

---

If you know you have monthly data you have one entry in each month you can order the data and create a sequence column.

```
df <- df[order(df$date), , drop = FALSE]
df$month <- 1:nrow(df)
```

In `dplyr` that would be -

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(date) %>% mutate(month = row_number())
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)[order(date), month = .I]
```